# подсветка синтаксиса scss

Tags: python, sublime-text, scss, sublime-text-3, синтаксис

Использую методологию `БЭМ` при написании `scss`. Для подсветки синтаксиса уставил плагин `SCSS`, но при написании такого когда, он его подсвечивает. Как сделать исключение или убрать такую подсветку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]